# How do VoIP services connect to landlines?

Tags: voip, infrastructure

How do VoIP services, such as Skype and Yahoo, connect to landlines?

We have a server connected to a landline using asterisk, so I'm thinking this server will bridge our VoIP conversation and connect it to a landline.

But if this is the case, wouldn't Skype need a lot of servers placed around the whole world just to connect to landlines?

Comment: I voted to close: "not programming related".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  That's how telephony works.  It's unlikely that Skype runs a bunch of servers themselves - they probably license the right to use a commercial telephony service, probably through the backbone carriers (just speculating).

Comment: Oh ya.. That doesn't occur to me. The carrier has some agreements with skype or yahoo so they don't need to put the server all around the world.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to call somebody using landlines with VoIP, you need a server somewhere that is connected to the landlines.